# PHP echo and use of &

Tags: php

I have a variable specified earlier in my script and using the & character, otherwise the script errors out with EntityRef: expecting ';' when using a & character:

```
$url = "http://www.domain.com/residential?frame=RESI&amp;MLNumber=";
```

The problem is that later in the script I use this variable like:

```
echo '<link>' . $url . '' . $title . '</link>';
```

The problem is that the end result is a bad URL like this:

```
http://www.domain.com/residential?frame=RESI&amp;base=frames&amp;MLNumber=26524589
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: And what specifically is bad about that URL? Would you care to point out the flaw?

Comment: "The problem is that later in the script I use this variable like:" ?

Comment: &amp; showing up in the URL does not work, it has to translate to a & which it is not.

Comment: Your problem is that `&` shouldn't be `&amp;` in your `$url` to begin with.  It should be `&`.  If you're getting this URL from an external source, you'll have to decode it.  If you're the one creating these URLs, then stop encoding the `&` until you're echoing into an HTML context.

Comment: The above answer should be the solution, it led me in the right direction to do it correctly.